# Disable Left ALT + Button 1 Grab and Move Window Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: unity, compiz

I know this might be a duplicate, but it was intended for lower version of Ubuntu. Since I am using Ubuntu 18.04, I tried the old solutions, but its not working. I tried to disabled it through compiz move plugin, after I saved it, its still there. It won't disable even I uncheck and click ok

Comment: Are you using Unity for sure? 18.04 comes with GNOME instead of Unity by default.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Ubuntu 18.04 with the default desktop environment (GNOME), installing the GNOME Tweak Tool with `sudo apt install gnome-tweaks` will give you an option to disable this.

Comment: Could you expand your answer a bit more? Which option exactly is to disable and where does one find it? GNOME Tweaks provide so many options that it's pretty easy to get lost there :)